# Remote script execute causes Docker stack deploy to fail

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

For testing purposes, I have a three line script (shebang not shown):

```
docker stack rm MYSTACK
sleep 30
docker stack deploy --compose-file /full/path/to/docker-compose.yml MYSTACK > output.txt
```

When I run this script locally/directly from a terminal window, it works as expected.  The output.txt file contains expected output of "Create network", "Creating service", etc. etc.

However, when I run from another machine (via ssh, if that matters), the running stack IS successfully stopped.  I can verify via `docker ps` all containers are gone while `ps -ef | grep sleep` shows the `sleep 30` is still active.  A new output.txt IS created, but is completely empty and nothing is started whatsoever.  Can anyone explain?  Docker 17.06.